# An error occurred while installing blackberry sdk5.0 on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

i am getting this below error when i try to install the Blackberry 5.0 sdk from Eclipse helios(downloaded from BB site with the BB sdk 7.0) and it downloads the sdk jar and then throw me this below error?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/auth/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=EF73B8E6C5570A3E25806E3C73616BD0.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

An All-In-One IDE can now be downloaded for BlackBerry Java development from:

https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse/

with the ability to pick and choose your SDKs and good integration with the Eclipse IDE, so there is no longer a need to integrate the SDK with your own previous workspace environment. The newer IDE package can sit as a standalone IDE and run alongside other instances of Eclipse